# unable to see ng-model

Tags: angularjs, django

i am trying to use angular js with django server

here is the index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

    <html ng-app="blog">
        <head>
            <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/libs/angular.min.js' %}"></script>
            <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/app.module.js' %}"></script>
            <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/app.config.js' %}"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <input type="text" ng-model="name">
            <p>hi , {{name}}</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

here is app.module.js

```
'use strict'

angular.module('blog' , []);
```

here is app.config.js

```
'use strict'

angular.module('blog').config(function(){});
```

the ng-model variable `name` doesnt show up at all.No error occurs and nothing comes up on typing anything in the input box

What can be the case and how can i recover from it ?

Comment: try remove [], use ``var blog = angular.module('blog');``

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**html**

```
<html>
      <head>
           <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/libs/angular.min.js' %}"></script>
           <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/app.module.js' %}"></script>
           <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/app.config.js' %}"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-app="myBlog">
           <input type="text" ng-model="name">
           <p>hi , {{name}}</p>
      </body>
</html>
```

**js**

```
'use strict';

var myBlog = angular.module('myBlog');

myBlog.config(function() {
   // anything u want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

angular module has a module registery, so you don't have to save your module somewhere. Actually you can even use IIFE pattern (Immediate Invocation Function Expression) to wrap your module definition ! 
My suggestion is to check weither it comes from the server itself. I mean check if your files are properly loaded !
Then wrap your logic inside a controller :

```
// -- my-blog.controller.js --
angular.module('blog', ['$scope', MyBlogCtrl($scope) {

}]);
```

in your index.html:

```
<html>
      <head>
           <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/libs/angular.min.js' %}"></script>
           <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/app.module.js' %}"></script>
           <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/app.config.js' %}"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-app="myBlog">
           <div ng-controller="MyBlogCtrl">
               <input type="text" ng-model="name">
               <p>hi , {{name}}</p>
           </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the need of defining a controller here.